# Cold water faucets plugged

Tags: plumbing

We live at the end of the service line and all of our cold water faucets keep plugging off down to a trickle.  How do we stop this and how do we fix it?

Comment: Google: [whole house filter](https://www.google.com/search?q=whole+house+filter&biw=1024&bih=639&tbm=shop&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim3cvtkJDKAhVE9WMKHYmeCZYQ_AUIBygB&dpr=1).

Comment: Plugging with what? It shouldn't matter where on the line you are.

Answer (score 1):

If they are plugging with debris (scale, etc. from inside the supply pipes), you prevent it by intercepting that debris with a filter when the water first enters your house, and you fix it (in most cases) by removing the aerators (which have a fine mesh screen) and flushing both the faucets (by running them without the aerators until the water runs clear) and the aerators themselves (by running water backwards through them until clean.)

If larger debris is plugging the valve itself before the aerator, it's a larger job to fix.

Comment: Aerators are sometimes best disassembled. Removing the faucet, putting a pot over the outlet pipe so as to protect the ceiling and turning the water on often works to clear junk out of mineraled up pipes.